# How to count number of occurrences of a substring inside a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

I am attempting to write a code snippet that requests from the user to enter a string `s` and then a substring `ss`. The program will then have to count the number of occurrences of `ss` in `s`. For example if the user enters `s = ‘azcbobobegghakl’` and `ss = ‘bob’`, then the program should print: Number
of times bob occurs is: 2.

Here is my code so far :

```
def count(s,ss):
    Occurrence = 0
    if ss in s :
        for ss in s :
            Occurrence += 1
    return Occurrence 

#Main program : 
    
s = str(input("Choose a string: "))
    
ss = str(input("Choose a substring:")) 
    
print ("Number of times " + str(ss) + " occurs is : " + str(count(s,ss)) )
```

My desired output would be this:

```
Choose a string: hellohel
Choose a substring:hel
Number of times hel occurs is : 2
```

But instead I get this :

```
Choose a string: hellohel
Choose a substring:hel
Number of times hel occurs is : 8
```

So can someone please help me modify  this code to deliver the desire output? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `count`

```
print("hellohel".count("hel"))
```

```
2
```

If you want to count overlapping occurrences... maybe this can help

```
def countOverlapping(string, item):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if item in string[i:len(item)+i]:
            count += 1
    return count

print(countOverlapping("ehehe", "ehe"))
```

output should be...

```
2
```

How does that work?

as @SomeDude mentioned it uses what he calls a sliding window approach

we take the length of the substring and check if its in that "window" of the string each iteration:

```
is ehe in [ehe]he? yes, count += 1
is ehe in e[heh]e? no, pass
is ehe in eh[ehe]? yes, count += 1
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks Ironkey.

Comment: No problem, if you liked a particular answer/explanation you can click the green checkmark to accept it for people with this question in the future, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for a sliding window approach to get count of substrings in a string.

example:

string : "ehehehe"

substring : "ehe"

start with first 3 ( because length of substring is 3 ) letters "ehe"- is it the substring we are looking for? - yes.

now leave the first letter "e" and combine letters "he" with the next letter "h" to form "heh" is it the substring we are looking for? - no

now leave the first letter "h" and combine letters "eh" with the next letter "e" to form "ehe" is it the substring we are looking for ? yes

do it till the end of the string and count number of "yes"s

Comment: Thanks for the help dude.